# Why does the Matsya purana mention mention that certain Puranas predominantly venerate Brahmā when not even a single purana of that category exists?

Tags: puranas, brahma, matsya-purana, rajasic, mahapuranas

Matsya Purana says-

> The glory of Hari is greater in Sattvika Puranas; **the glory of Brahma
> is greater in Rajasika Puranas**; and that of Agni and Shiva greater in
> Tamasika Puranas. In mixed Puranas, the glory of Sarasvati and the
> pitrs is said to be greater.

(Matsya Purana, Chapter 53, Verses 67-68)

But not even a single Purana out of the 18 mahapuranas or even the Upapuranas have Brahmā as the predominantly glorified diety. So how does this even make sense?